# jar File Becomes Corrupted After Being Sent Over Socket IF It Was Sent In Pieces

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have been trying to work this problem out for a few hours now, but nothing seems to help. This is a problem out of my FOV.

So basically what i'm trying to do is send a jar file over a socket. I setup my ServerSocket, wait for connection, connect to it. After connecting I setup ObjectStreams. Then I send a request from client-side for download. Server receives that message and reacts accordingly: starts a thread which sends a file over a socket to the client. It opens the file using FileInputStream, takes the length of the file in bytes. Then it sends the file in pieces of X bytes. I tried many values here. The only time I successfully send a jar file over a socket, is when I send all the bytes at once. If I send bytes 2 times, (half the first time, seconds half after it), then my sent jar file won't work anymore, it becomes corrupted.

It becomes corrupted only with some values. With others, when I try to run it, nothing happens. So I ran in in CMD and turns out I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.ninjacave.jarsplice.JarSpliceLauncher.extractNatives(JarSpliceLauncher.java:140)
        at org.ninjacave.jarsplice.JarSpliceLauncher.<init>(JarSpliceLauncher.java:63)
        at org.ninjacave.jarsplice.JarSpliceLauncher.main(JarSpliceLauncher.java:234)
```

So my question is this: do objects sent over a socket get modified in some way or what? Because all the things in my sent file are present, but it doesn't seem to launch properly or gets corrupted. + I have run out of moves.. If you want to see code I can show it.

Ok. Code for breaking into pieces.

```
public void run() {

        FileInputStream fileStream = null;

        try {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }




        long length = file.length(), done = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[step];



        try {

            int counter = 0;


            while(done + step < length) {
                fileStream.read(buffer);
                output.writeObject(new Data(buffer, counter));
                done+=step;
                counter+=1;
            }



            int last = (int)(length - done);
            byte[] lastBuffer = new byte[last];
            fileStream.read(lastBuffer);
            output.writeObject(new Data(lastBuffer, counter));



            output.writeObject(new Message(null, Message.SEND_COMPLETED));
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }







        try {
            fileStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Gluing the file back:

```
obj = in.readObject();
if(obj instanceof Data) {
   Data dat = (Data)obj;
   fileWriter.write(dat.buffer);
}
```

Data class:

```
package act;
```

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Data implements Serializable{

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3070641500586981886L;
public byte[] buffer;
public int counter = 0;

public Data(byte[] buffer, int counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
    this.buffer = buffer;
}
```

}

Here is some kind of "example" program I made for myself to see if my program actually works without networking. And it does.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    File fileSource = new File("tosend.jar");
    File fileDest = new File("C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/downloader/Testing/dest/dest.jar");

    try {

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileSource);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileDest);



        long length = fileSource.length(), done = 0;
        int step = 1000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[step];

        while(done + step < length) {
            in.read(buffer);
            out.write(buffer);
            done+=step;
        }

        int last = (int)(length - done);
        buffer = new byte[last];
        in.read(buffer);
        out.write(buffer);

        in.close();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Writing compleete!");
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is your code for putting the pieces together? I believe there's an error in the way you put the pieces together, or the way you send the pieces.

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have the usual problem. You are ignoring the result of the read() method. Try this, at both ends:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

No need for Object streams at all. This works with any size buffer > 0.

Comment: I'm not "ignoring the result".
My sent file has exactly the same byte size as the source one.

Comment: You have `in.read(buffer)` without storing the result into a variable. Ergo you are ignoring it. QED. You are therefore also assuming that the read fills the buffer. When it doesn't, which it doesn't, you are therefore writing junk into your file. You could always try it, instead of just arguing. You wouldn't be posting if your code really was perfect.